# How to Use RequireJS with Backbone, Firebase, and Backfire

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, firebase

I am trying to use RequireJS, Backbone, Firebase, and Backfire together in a project and am having a real hard time getting started. Here is a simple example:

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        backbone: 'backbone',
        backfire: 'backfire',
        firebase: 'firebase',
        underscore: 'underscore',
        jquery: 'jquery',

        test: 'test'
    },

    shim: {
        'firebase': {
            exports: 'Firebase'
        },

        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },

        'backbone': {
            deps: [ 'underscore', 'jquery' ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },

        'backfire': {
            deps: [ 'backbone', 'firebase', 'underscore' ]
        }
    }
});

requirejs([ 'test' ]);
```

**test.js**

```
define([ 'backbone', 'firebase', 'backfire' ], function( Backbone, Firebase ){
    var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: function() {
            return {
                fName: 'John',
                lName: 'Doe'
            };
        }
    });

    var database = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
        model: Person,

        firebase: new Firebase( 'https://ref.firebaseio.com' )
    });

    console.log( typeof database ); // function

    // The following throws "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"
    database.add( new Person({ fName: 'Matthew', lName: 'Hasbach' }));
});
```

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that since Firebase internally does some requests of its own, that you need to wait for the Firebase object to be instantiated. Requirejs has a test method (I don't remember the syntax) to wait for an object to initialize before it is considered loaded. You'll need to utilize that.

Comment: @Kato Good afternoon. ```Firebase``` is fully instantiated when the define callback function is executed in **test.js**. I tested this by bypassing ```Backbone``` completely, creating a ```new Firebase```, and setting a test value. Please see my revised question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jgillich stated in his answer, I was not instantiating `Backbone.Firebase.Collection`. However, it is important to note that in Backbone, in order to define and instantiate a collection in the same assignment, the `extend` method cannot be used. Instead, `new Backbone.Collection` must be used. This also applies to other Backbone objects, like models.

**However**, definition and instantiation of `Backbone.Firebase.Collection` (at the time of this writing) must be split into separate assignments. It would appear that `new Backbone.Firebase.Collection` is not supported. Here is an example:

**test.js**

```
define([ 'backbone', 'firebase', 'backfire' ], function( Backbone, Firebase ){
    var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: function() {
            return {
                fName: 'John',
                lName: 'Doe'
            };
        }
    });

    var Database = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
        model: Person,

        firebase: new Firebase( 'https://ref.firebaseio.com' )
    });

    var db = new Database;

    // Success!
    db.add( new Person({ fName: 'Matthew', lName: 'Hasbach' }));

    // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined
    var nope = new Backbone.Firebase.Collection({
        model: Person,

        firebase: new Firebase( 'https://ref.firebaseio.com' )
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate your collection first (using `new`).

```
var database = new Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
    model: Person,
    firebase: new Firebase( 'https://ref.firebaseio.com' )
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot, but I was not able to define and instantiate ```database``` in the same assignment like your example. I had to do ```var database = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend(...)``` and then ```var db = new database``` in order for it to work. If you can address this in your answer, I will accept it. I am new to Backbone and would love to know if this "problem" is specific only to ```Backbone.Firebase.Collection``` or to all Backbone collections.